# no affect of limit on cursor time aggrgate mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, limit, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

I am aggregating Data on a collection having 1 million records. 
Match query uses index.
Find Code reference below -

```
    AggregateIterable<Document> aggregateIterable = timeCollection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(match, project,group)).batchSize(1000).allowDiskUse(true);
    long curStartTs = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    MongoCursor<Document> cursor = aggregateIterable.iterator(); //this line roughly takes 15 seconds
    long curEndTs = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    System.out.println("Cursor time - " + (curEndTs - curStartTs));
```

The final resultant list contains 3500 records.

Now I am limiting the records by passing **$limit** in the aggregate pipeline as -

```
    Document limitParam = new Document("$limit",30);
    AggregateIterable<Document> aggregateIterable = timeCollection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(match, project,group,limitParam)).batchSize(1000).allowDiskUse(true);
    long curStartTs = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    MongoCursor<Document> cursor = aggregateIterable.iterator(); //this line still taking around 15 seconds
    long curEndTs = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    System.out.println("Cursor time - " + (curEndTs - curStartTs));
```

The final resultant list contains now only 30 records.

I am not able to understand that why there is no time variation in two cases.
Even after providing the limit in pipeline, why **aggregateIterable.iterator()** is taking the same time as that of the case when there is no limit in pipeline?

Thanks a lot in advance.

kind regards,

Vibhav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Aggregation $limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) has no effect on the content of the documents it passes.

By Seeing your code

```
long curStartTs = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = aggregateIterable.iterator(); //this line roughly takes 15 seconds
long curEndTs = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
System.out.println("Cursor time - " + (curEndTs - curStartTs));
```

You are trying to find the time taken just for executing the query.

To get a better idea of how much time actually taken in MongoDB to execute these queries we can execute the same queries in mongo shell with `explain`

Sample Queries

> Without Limit

```
db.foo.aggregate([ { 'conditions' }], {explain: true})
```

> With Limit

```
db.foo.aggregate([{ 'conditions' }, {$limit: 10}], {explain: true})
```

Also you may need to look on [Performance of MongoDB query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/analyzing-mongodb-performance/) , [Optimize Query](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/optimize-query-performance-with-indexes-and-projections/), [Analyze Query Plan](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/analyze-query-plan/) and [cursor limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/method/cursor.limit/#cursor.limit)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks @Clement. This was very helpful.!